# scikit-neuralnetwork on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

We are trying to run scikit-neuralnetwork<sup>[1]</sup> in a raspberry pi zero running Raspbian.

We have searched in apt-get and couldn't find an available version. We have tried compiling it in the raspberry and (after a couple of hours) it failed.

What's the best way to install it in the raspberry? Is it available in any repository that we might be missing? Or is there a way to compile it for arm in some other computer (ie. PC running ubuntu) faster than on the pi zero itself?

Thanks,
Jorge

[1] http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This writeup on scientific python for the raspberry pi might be helpful: http://geoffboeing.com/2016/03/scientific-python-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @neelshiv: We installed scikit-learn from apt-get without problems. scikit-neuralnetwork (sknn) is a different library and we are only having issues for that one. Thanks for the link anyway

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood. Good luck! Hopefully somebody here can help.